# Getting Kendo UI ComboBox element (embedded into EditorTemplate) from JS script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox, kendo-ui, telerik

I have some problems with Kendo UI ComboBox widget because I cannot reference it from my *main view* (javascript code). I going to sketch the views and scripts related out.

There's a main view that loads a **MainModelView** and it has also another **DetailModelView** as property that uses an EditorTemplate to render the form. That DetailModelView has a Kendo UI ComboBox (MVC.NET)

Here is (more or less) the files involved:

- MainView.cshtml (loads main.js file)     (uses) MainModelView that has
  another model as property (uses DetailViewModel)
  --DetailView.cshtml 
  (Editor Template inside correct folder for DetailModelView, loads detailview.js file).

  DetailView.cshtml contains:

  ```
  @(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.EngineerID)
       .HtmlAttributes(new { @class= "engineer" })
                 ...............
  )
  ```

That renders the client id, a compounded name "DetailViewModel_EngineerID".
Problems start when trying to get combo box from main.js (seems to be impossible). It does not work:

```
var combo = $('#DetailViewModel_EngineerID').data("kendoComboBox"); //element by direct id
```

neither

```
var combo = $('[ID$=EngineerID]').data("kendoComboBox"); //element by client id generated
```

even

```
var combo = $(".engineer").data("kendoComboBox"); //get element by class
```

returning both ways 'undefined' but$("[ID$=engineers]") returns the following:

```
[input#EngineerID.engineer, prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1], context: document, selector: "[ID$=engineers]", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function…]0: input#EngineerID.engineercontext: documentlength: 1prevObject: b.fn.b.init[1]selector: "[ID$=engineers]"__proto__: b[0]
```

**Incredibly it works only if called within detailview.js that is attached directly to DetailView.cshtml:**

```
       console.log($("[ID$=EngineerID]").data("kendoComboBox"));
```

returns ->

```
o.extend.init {ns: ".kendoComboBox", element: k.fn.init[1], _events: Object, options: Object, _isSelect: false…}_arrow: k.fn.init[1]_bound: true_busy: null_current: k.fn.init[1]_errorHandler: function (){return e.apply(n||this,r.concat(h.call(arguments)))}_events: Object_focusHandler: function (){a.input.focus()}_focused: k.fn.init[1]_form: k.fn.init[1]_initial: ""_inputWrapper: k.fn.init[1]_isSelect: false_old: ""_oldIndex: -1_optionID: "EngineerID_option_selected"_progressHandler: function (){return e.apply(n||this,r.concat(h.call(arguments)))}_refreshHandler: function (){return e.apply(n||this,r.concat(h.call(arguments)))}_request: false_requestEndHandler: function (){return e.apply(n||this,r.concat(h.call(arguments)))}_resetHandler: function (){setTimeout(function(){t.value(t._initial)})}_text: function anonymous(d_touchScroller: false_value: function anonymous(ddataSource: lt.extend.initelement: k.fn.init[1]input: k.fn.init[1]list: k.fn.init[1]ns: ".kendoComboBox"options: Objectpopup: r.extend.initselectedIndex: -1template: function anonymous(dataul: k.fn.init[1]wrapper: k.fn.init[1]__proto__: n.extend.r
```

that is the Kendo combo box I'm looking for but it does not work if I try to get outside the scope of DetailView.

I hope this explanation could help you to have a better overview about this issue.

This DetailView is being used by some views and not all of them have to implement the functionality I need so I cannot bind the action to the ComboBox events and need to catch whether the combo is empty or not to add a new item using a ajax call refreshing the combobox after item has been saved successfully (success response in ajax call) and all these actions/events must be done from *main.js*

This seems to be a problem about scopes where the element are rendered but don't know really. Thank you

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: Hi Brett, This is the output:

Comment: I'm confused. Can you provide a jsBin or jsFiddle example?

Comment: It's really difficult to show a functional project or build a sample because a bunch of views and view models are implicated It is like if the combo box were not visible from outside the view that renders it (has the code).What I added in my previous answer was the HTML code that Kendo widget renders. It suppose you can get access to that widget (the element that builds the combo / feeds the input) using that ID but it does not work so you cannot bind event actions from outside the combo itself: @Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m=>m.EngineerID)........Events(ev=>ev.DataBound("onDataBound")....

Answer (score 0):

This is the output:

```
<input class="engineer" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Engineer must be a number." data-val-required="Please select an engineer." id="JobDetails_EngineerID" name="JobDetails.EngineerID" type="text" /><script>
jQuery(function(){jQuery("#JobDetails_EngineerID").kendoComboBox({"change":onEngineerChange,"dataBound":onEngineerDataBound,"dataSource":{"transport":{"read":{"url":"/SelectList/Engineers","data":function() { return kendo.ui.ComboBox.requestData("#JobDetails_EngineerID"); },"type":"POST"},"prefix":""},"serverFiltering":true,"filter":[],"schema":{"errors":"Errors"}},"dataTextField":"Text","autoBind":true,"dataValueField":"Value","placeholder":"Engineer","suggest":true});});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just struggling with a similar possibly the same issue and landed on this SO question.

The issue I believe is that kendo ui will create a new input element copy from the original input. Thus, your selector is probably not selecting the original input used to initialize the widget.

To fix I added a html5 data attribute to the original input. I didn't use kendo configuration but I'm guessing something like this:

```
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class= "engineer", @data_original_input= "true" })
```

Then to select with jquery:

```
$('.engineer[data-original-input="true"]').data("kendoComboBox");
```